# Problem Loading Picture on DataList using Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

It is Web browser compatibility issue?

When i used IE its show up my images and When I tried Mozilla Firefox it show nothings..

here's my code:

```
<td style="width: 216px; height: 50px;">
<asp:Image ID="img_Events" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="62px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("le_picturepath") %>' /></td>
```

Comment: You need to add a semi-colon after the 50px

Comment: could you possibly show an example of le_picturepath?

Answer (score 1):

Use **ResolveUrl property**
Try this it will work.

```
<td style="width: 216px; height: 50px;">
     <asp:Image ID="img_Events" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="62px" ImageUrl='<%#ResolveUrl ("~/" + Eval("le_picturepath")) %>' /></td>
```

Comment: <td style="width: 216px; height: 50px;">
<asp:Image ID="img_Events" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="62px" ImageUrl='<%#ResolveUrl ("~/" + Eval("le_picturepath")) %>' /></td>

Comment: Instead of posting unformatted code in a comment, you should update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have an image of height 40px in a table cell of height 18px. It should still display in that it it should push the table cell up. Try correcting this and then check the HTML being generated to see if the image is in the markup...

You should also have an alt attribute.